# How to add controls from another class to a form vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, controls

How can you add a control from a different class into the main form? I tried different approaches, either adding the control from inside its class or adding it in a function inside the main form class. Here is my actual code:

```
Public Class Game
    Private Sub Play_bp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Play_bp.Click
        Me.main_panel.Hide()
        Dim joueur = New Player()
        Me.game_panel.Controls.Add(joueur.Image)
        Me.game_panel.Show()
        joueur.Image.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Quit_bp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Quit_bp.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Player
#Region "Player Attribute"
    Public m_speed As Integer
    Public m_image As PictureBox
    Public m_munition As UInteger
    Public m_life As UInteger
    Public m_position As Point
#Region "Player Functions"
    Public Sub New()
        Me.m_life = 3
        Me.m_munition = 10
        Me.m_position = New Point(100, 200)
        Me.m_image = New PictureBox
        Me.m_image.Image = My.Resources.player
        Me.m_image.Location = Me.m_position 
    End Sub

    Public Sub Fire()
        If me_munition> 0 Then

        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Move(decalage As Integer)
        If decalage < 0 Then 'Décalage vers la gauche
            'Si on peut bouger vers la gauche
            If (Me.me_position.X + decalage) > 0 Then
                Me.me_position= New Point(Me.me_position.X + decalage, Me.me_position.Y)
            End If
        ElseIf decalage > 0 Then 'Décalage vers la droite
            'Si on peut bouger vers la droite
            If (Me.me_position.X + decalage) < Game.Width Then
                Me.me_position= New Point(Me.me_position.X + decalage, Me.me_position.Y)
            End If
        End If
        Me.Image().Location= Me.me_position
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

edit: I tried to display the image inside the UI code but it doesn't work either. I am still getting a black window without my picture:

```
Private Sub Play_bp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Play_bp.Click
        Me.main_panel.Hide()
        Me.vue_actuelle = Vues.Game

        Dim Player_picture = New PictureBox
        Player_picture.Size = New Size(My.Resources.player_mini.Width, My.Resources.player_mini.Height)
        Player_picture.Image = My.Resources.player_mini
        Player_picture.Location = New Point(100, 200)

        Me.game_panel.Controls.Add(Player_picture)
        Me.game_panel.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean like a custom control?

Comment: what do you mean by "add a control from a Class"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As a school project, I have to do a space invaders in vb net. In the code, I have a class player which contains a picturebox. My main form contains 2 panels, one for the menu and one for the game. I'm trying to display my picturebox inside the game panel.

Comment: You just need to picture from the picture box, not the control itself. Ideally the game panel would have it's own designated spot for the pic I imagine

Comment: Actually, I would like to handle the drawing from the player class. Every time the player needs to move it would change the position of the picturebox and since the picturebox would be in the game panel it should be redrawn automatically.

Comment: @Godrod There's a homework way to do this (what you're doing is probably fine as long as your instructor approves) and there is a *right* way which involves a separation of program logic and the UI. Having a UI element, the PictureBox, in the Player class will probably slow down your application. I would at most have a Bitmap in the Player class, though I'm not even sure about that. The class should raise events to which the UI responds. The class should operate off the UI thread. But since this is homework, you're probably not concerned about that. Still we need more info.

Comment: From memory `PictureBox`s added at runtime are by default not visible. Try `Player_picture.Visible = True`

Comment: @SSS I tried but it still doesn't work